# Is cypress.io capable of executing test automation on desktop application?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, desktop-application

I'm currently working for a client whose request is to make a test automation for a desktop application. And they recommended using cypress.io, which i think was built mainly for web automation. I tried looking to their docs but it seems I can't find anything that enables it to run desktop app automation. Sorry for the noob question, I'm still a newbie here. 
Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 3):

cypress.io is not capable of automating desktop apps. 
(Source: Did a brief POC couple of weeks back with Cypress.io)

Cypress is more about a web application automation framework. This means if the application can run in a browser, Cypress can automate it.

Even their GitHub project header says the same :)
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress

[image]